# Meaning of QML warning

Tags: qml, qt5

In my application I have a very simple UI written in `QML` using `Qt 5.5.1` on `OS X El Capitan`. I have a layout with tabs that are loaded with a `Loader` component when I switch from tab to tab.

On startup, `tab1` loads, it is correctly populated with data and I get no warnings. If I cause `tab1` to reload, for instance by switching to `tab2`, which sets the `source` of my `Loader` and then back to `tab1`, I get the following warnings.

> warning: AbstractCheckable_QMLTYPE_13 QVariant(Invalid) QRect(0,0 0x0)
>
> warning: QQuickText QVariant(Invalid) QRect(1820,850 0x0)
>
> warning: CheckBox_QMLTYPE_15 QVariant(Invalid) QRect(1820,850 0x0)
>
> warning: QQuickText QVariant(Invalid) QRect(1820,850 0x0)

This problem isn't limited to just `tab1`. When I switch to `tab2` I get similar types of warnings. If I hack my app to launch with `tab2` instead of `tab1`, I get no warnings for `tab2` on startup, so this appears to be a warning generated only when reloading the `source` of my `Loader` not on first load.

I haven't found any documentation about deciphering the meaning of these warnings. I've tried various fixes to my `QML` but the fact that it loads without warnings the first time leads me to believe the problem may lie elsewhere.

===

Update, I've provided a reasonably minimal implementation that illustrates this problem [here](https://gist.github.com/agentsim/bb466c86acc7b89a27d4).

`Main.qml` has the `Loader` component that loads `Tab1.qml` or `Tab2.qml` depending on which `RadioButton` is checked.

Using `qmlscene`, I get no warnings on startup. But once I switch between tabs I see the following warnings:

> QQuickText QVariant(Invalid) QRect(735,370 0x0)
>
> QQuickText QVariant(Invalid) QRect(735,370 0x0)

Comment: Updated with example code.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I've tested the code on my El Capitain machine as well as on a Win machine. Actually I've used a `QQmlApplicationEngine`, instead of `qmlscene` and everything worked fine. I wound't be wrong but I guess it's a bug in `qmlscene` that we are seeing here. Possibly [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48593). I don't think you are using `qmlscene` in your real application, though.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using `qmlscene` in my real application. As I originally said, I don't think the problem lies with the `qml` code, after all it loads properly. I think it lies elsewhere, hence what I really want to know is, what do the warnings mean.

Comment: Confirmed. The message simply means that a `QRect` is not valid. This is happening while trying to get the `state` of a `QAccessibleQuickItem`. Unfortunately I don't see a way to work around it.